# malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom

Tags: json, perl, parsing

I have trouble parsing a json object with perl and I don't know if the issue is coming from the json or my script. Here is the json:

**test.json**

```
{
   "count":3,
   "entries": 
   [
      {
         "id":85,
         "application":AuditExampleLogin1,
         "user":admin,
         "time":"2011-11-22T10:29:37.422Z",
         "values":
null
      },
      {
         "id":87,
         "application":AuditExampleLogin1,
         "user":admin,
         "time":"2011-11-22T10:30:56.235Z",
         "values":
null
      },
      {
         "id":89,
         "application":AuditExampleLogin1,
         "user":admin,
         "time":"2011-11-22T10:33:15.000Z",
         "values":
null
      }
   ]
}
```

Here the script:
**script.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use JSON;
open FILE, 'test.json' or die "Could not open file inputfile: $!";
sysread(FILE, my $result, -s FILE);
close FILE or die "Could not close file: $!"; 
my @json = @{decode_json($result)};
```

And finally the error I'm getting:
**error**

```
malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom,
at character offset 86 (before "AuditExampleLogin1,\n...") at     
./script.pl line 7.
```

**Q: Can someone tell me whether the issue is coming from the json or my script and what to change in either case?**

FYI the [json is coming from Alfresco auditing api](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Auditing_%28from_V3.4%29).

Comment: AFAIK that's not valid JSON, missing quotes around the values.

Comment: I was dealing with the exactly same problem. I have a question to the thread author: how do you access the @json variables? I keep geting that @json is a HASH in the memory but I can`t access  the variables or loop trough it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if the Audit... and admin values are quoted.  The line

```
my @json = @{decode_json($result)};
```

needs to be just

```
my @json = decode_json($result);
```

Comment: indeed it works when `application` and `user` values are quoted. Is there a way to tell `perl` to be a bit more loose on the parsing of JSON and accept unquoted strings? (that would save me from having to rewrite the json).

Comment: Not sure, the JSON module author considers strict checking to be a security feature. You might poke at the code, JSON::PP is a pure perl version.

Comment: You're asking a JSON parser to successfully parse data that isn't valid JSON. That way lies madness, surely :)

Answer (score 12):

This:

```
"application":AuditExampleLogin1,
```

… is invalid JSON. `AuditExampleLogin1` isn't an array, object, number, string or atom. I don't know what it is supposed to be, so I can't tell you what to change it to.

If it is a string, then you need to enclose it in `"`.

See also: [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/).